# How should I determine how far apart the markers of two points are?

Tags: matplotlib

In Matplotlib, is there an idiomatic way to tell how far apart two markers are with the present zoom level and marker style? Or, even better, is there a way to determine how much two markers overlap?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm making some plots that are sort of like scatter plots, wherein two points at the same coordinate (or very very nearby) has significant meaning, and it's important that I know when the (identical) symbols used for the points obscure each other. I want to determine the degree to which the symbols (again, for the chosen symbol type, size and zoom level) overlap, and amend the plot with some text to signify the degeneracies.

Comment: It gets tricky because markers are sized in pixels, but they are spaced in data units (that is the markers stay the same size, no matter how much you zoom).  To do what you want you will have to dig into the transform stack.  I would also look into giving your markers `alpha=.1` or so which will allow you to see overlaps as darker regions.